# upload file with progresss bar and delete option in php

Tags: php, html

I am creating file uploader with showing progress bar and the close button but there are some major problems with these code.it shows the progress bar continuesly.and the main problem is it delete the file but then after it refresh the page and my all uploaded files are not visible to me from which i want to delete some file.
 i just want to creator file downloader like gmail provides the facility of multiple file attachment at same time with progress bar and close button for the file which uploaded by mistak by the user.

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() { 

                $('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function()
                { 
                           //$("#preview").html('');

                    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
                         beforeSubmit:function(){ 

                        console.log('ttest');
                        $("#imageloadstatus").show();
                         $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
                         }, 
                        success:function(){ 
                        console.log('test');
                         $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                         $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                        }, 
                        error:function(){ 
                        console.log('xtest');
                         $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
                        $("#imageloadbutton").show();
                        } }).submit();


                });
            }); 
    </script>

    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
    /**
    * Multi file upload example
    * @author Resalat Haque
    * @link http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html
    **/

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp","doc","docx");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
    $path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
    $count = 0;

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip file if any error found
            }          
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                }
                else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
                                $path="uploads/".$name;
                                ?>
                                <div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'></div>
    <div id='imageloadbutton'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php           
                    echo "<a href=\"dl.php?file=".$name."\">".$name."</a>&nbsp;<a href=\"dl.php?file=".$name."\" >                          <img src='image/loader.gif' alt='Uploading....'/><img src=\"image/close.jpg\" /></a><br />"; 
                        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
            <?php
            # error messages
            if (isset($message)) {
                foreach ($message as $msg) {
                    printf("<p class='status'>%s</p></ br>\n", $msg);
                }
            }
            # success message

            if($count !=0){
                printf("<p class='status'>%d files added successfully!</p>\n", $count);
            }
            ?>
            <br />
    <?php } ?>      
            <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>

       <style type="text/css">
          /* Style goes here */ 
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <!-- Multiple file upload html form-->
            <form action="upload_demo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageform">

    <div id='preview'>
    </div>

                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="photoimg">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name='submit'>


            </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

file to delete dl.php

```
    <?php if(isset($_GET['file']))
            {
                $file=$_GET['file'];
                $path="uploads/".$file;
                unlink($path);
               // echo "The file: ".$file." has been deleted.";
            ?>
            <script> window.location.href = "upload_demo.php";          
            </script>
            <?php
            }  ?>
```

Comment: do you want such a behavior? http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: ya but file uploaded with doc,pdf,and image files like jpg,jpeg,png format

Comment: have a look at the docs [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypeexts/). you can specify the extensions that you want.

Comment: dl.php: what happens when someone will send an asterisk (*) ? do you check the userinput ?

Comment: its perfect but uploaded files are invisible after 1 or 2 second how overcome this problem

Comment: and also do not move files to destination folder

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use uploadify, you can do something like this:

your html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

   <style type="text/css">
      /* Style goes here */ 
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id='image-list'></ul>

        <!-- Multiple file upload html form-->
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageform">

    <input type='file' name='image-upload' id='image-upload' />
</form>
```

your javascript file:

```
function UploadifyInterface()
{
    var self = this;

    this.init = function()
    {
        $("#image-upload").uploadify({
            height        : 30,
            swf           : 'uploadify.swf',
            uploader      : $("#image-upload").closest("form").attr("action"),
            fileTypeDesc : 'Image Files',
            fileTypeExts : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
            onUploadSuccess     : function(file, data, response) {
            var image = data;
                self.addImage(image.imageId, image.imagePath);
            },
            width         : 120
        });
    }

    this.addImage = function(id, path)
    {
        var imagePath = path.substr(strpos(path, "/", 2));
        $("#image-list").append('<li><img width="120" height="120" src="'+imagePath+'" /><a href="/deleteimg">delete</a></li>');
        $("#image-list > li").width(125);
    }
}

var uploadify = new UploadifyInterface();
uploadify.init();
```

now you have to do some work on the php side:

name it Uploader.php

```
<?php

abstract class FileUpload
{
    abstract protected function PreProcessUpload($files);
    abstract protected function GetLastError();
    abstract protected function Response();

    public function ProcessFileUpload($callback, $args)
    {
        if (!isset($_FILES['Filedata']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']))
        {
            $response = array("error" => "File upload not valid!");
        }
        else if(!$this->PreProcessUpload($_FILES['Filedata']))
        {
            $response = $this->GetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            // processed trough a callbackfunction
            $args[count($args)] = $_FILES['Filedata'];
            call_user_func_array($callback, $args);

            $response = $this->Response();
        }

        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }
}

public class Uploader extends FileUpload
{
    private $error = NULL;
    private $response = NULL;
....
    protected function PreProcessUpload($files)
    {
        $size = @getimagesize($files['tmp_name']);
        $result['size'] = $size;
        if (($size[0] < 25) || ($size[1] < 25))
        {
            $this->response['error'] = 'Please upload an image bigger than 25px.';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected function GetLastError()
    {
        if(is_array($this->response) && isset($this->response['error']))
        {
            return $this->response;
        }
        return array("error" => '');
    }

    protected function Response()
    {
        if(is_array($this->response))
        {
            return $this->response;
        }
        return array();
    }

    public function processImageUpload($id, $uploadImageInfo)
    {
        /*  your processing here */
    }
 ....
}

?>
```

and then use the class:

name it upload_file.php

```
 <?php

 include("Uploader.php");

 $uploader = new Uploader();
 $uploader->ProcessFileUpload(array($uploader , "processImageUpload"), array($id));

 ?>
```

---

EDIT: added basic php / html / javascript file structure

Comment: is it posible with my php code can u help me with my php code please.because i cant get your code whaT U want to say i just use core php so i cant get where i have to place this code

Comment: i just want same like iploadfive i also download it but upload files links are not working

Comment: in uplodifive the link for uploading the files not working where i can change the code for link

Comment: `uploader      : $("#image-upload").closest("form").attr("action"),` or you use the one in the action attribute `<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageform">`